# Dialogflow works in test console, but not via google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a smart home dialogflow webhook working from the google actions test console, but when I speak to a google home device, there is no sign that my intents are being recognized. E.g., I enter “Home temperature?” in the console, I can see it calling my webhook, executing my script, and responding with “The temperature is 72 degrees.”

But when I say: “Hey Google, Home temperature” to my google home device, it says my nest device is not registered, or something like that. I.e., it is what it would say if I did not have smart home action intents registered with google actions.

I am unable to find anything in the docs or by web searches which says what I am supposed to do to get my google assistant devices to recognize my custom intent phrases.

Does anyone have this working? The Smart Home integration is not supposed to require a lead in, like “Hey Google, Ask whoever, Home temperature”, Right? That is only for “conversation mode” integrations, correct? My understanding is that “Smart Home” mode does not require a lead-in. Please correct me if that is incorrect…

Either way, my voice requests through my Google Home are not recognized.

Please, any advice for what I am missing or how I can troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm new to Stack Overflow, and I didn't find this "dialogflow" group until posting in another group.  So I am reposting here.  Sorry if this is redundant. I could not find how to delete the original post...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A couple of tips to using it. First - if you tagged this with something else, you could have re-tagged it here. (What did you originally tag it?) Second - this sounds like a Smart Home question, which should be tagged `actions-on-google`, unless you used the Dialogflow toolkit (which is very unusual for Smart Home), so you might want to clarify, as it impacts how to best help you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like I was wrong about the "Hey Google, talk to ..." requirement for Dialogflow.

The "Smart Home" mode does not preclude this.  You *cannot* just say, "Hey Google, home temperature?", you have to say, "Hey Google, ask [my dialogflow app], home temperature?"

Furthermore, unless you Publish your app, the response will always say, "Alright, here's the test version of [my dialogflow app]...

Between the two, it pretty much ruins it for me...  Off to the drawing board.